# Как тестировать работу со сторонним API к которому нет доступа?

Tags: веб-программирование, api

Делаю управляющий несколькими сторонними API сервис. К каждому стороннему API есть хорошая документация, но нету тестовых доступов (как при интернет-эквайринге в банках). Но как же тогда проверить правильность работы сервиса?